# Javascript Derived Value in CRM 2011 Form Header

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-2011

On form load in CRM 2011 there is basic javascript that is retrieving data from various sources (eg, Web Services) and populating form fields.  Some are read only and are only meant to be for reference only to provide more information about the entity the user is working with.

Instead of placing these fields on the form, we have noticed in moving to CRM 2011 from 4.0 that there is the ability to have a header and footer where you can place read-only fields that are always visible regardless of what sections of the form you navigate to.

Having moved these javascript-populated fields (that worked in the body of the form) to the header and footer they simply do not work and a javascript error is visible in the status bar of IE (that we cannot get a proper error message out of).

Has anyone had any success with doing such a thing?  Or have we stumbled across yet another quirky CRM 2011 bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the fields are in the header, they're not part of the actual CRM form, and can't be changed. You should be able to create HTML and JavaScript web resources to accomplish the same thing you're talking about, and plop that in the header or on the form. Then you don't even need to create fields to hold your temporary data.

Comment: Will try the web resource in the header - need to confirm if that is possible.